# How to get sum of two text fields and set to another text field in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How can I get the sum of two text fields and set it to another text field when changing the value in Laravel Nova? I want to get Quantity x Unit_Price and set it to Amount.

```
SimpleRepeatable::make('Purchase Order Items', 'purchase_order_items', [
    Select::make('Purchase_Order_Id')
        ->options(\App\Models\PurchaseOrder::pluck('serial_number', 'id'))
        ->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),
    Select::make('Product_id')->options(\App\Models\Product::pluck('product_name', 'id'))
        ->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),
    Text::make('Quantity'),
    Text::make('Unit_Price'),
    Text::make('Amount'),
    Select::make('Variant_id')
        ->options(\App\Models\Variant::pluck('productName', 'id'))
        ->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe i understood it wrong, but you can delete amount from database and make atribute amount through [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and then use it on your form and you can hide it from create and update

```
protected function amount(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn() => $this->quantity*$this->unit_price,
    );
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead

```
SimpleRepeatable::make('Purchase Order Items', 'purchase_order_items', [
    Select::make('Purchase_Order_Id')
        ->options(\App\Models\PurchaseOrder::pluck('serial_number', 'id'))
        ->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),
    Select::make('Product_id')->options(\App\Models\Product::pluck('product_name', 'id'))
        ->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),

    Number::make('Quantity'),
    Number::make('Unit_Price'),
    Text::make('Amount', function ($model) {
        return $model->quantity + $model->unit_price;
    }),

    Select::make('Variant_id')
        ->options(\App\Models\Variant::pluck('productName', 'id'))
        ->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),
])
```

As you can see Text fields are replaced with Number fields so that you can sum 2 fields and show the result in computed Amount field.

You can take a look at [computed fields](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#computed-fields) definition.

Comment: It says "Attempt to read property 'quantity' on null

Comment: @ijsegovindu is quantity a required field? if not then computed field will give error while trying to access quantity col from database.